# Why does magnetism move electrons in a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, induction

What is to account for at the atomic level which gives magnetism its force upon electrons in a conductor? Why does the Lorenz force work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric and magnetic force are transmitted by photons. This is covered in the theory of quantum electrodynamics:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics

Comment: So if i have neodymium magnet,it attract things with photons? What wavelenght are these photons?